# How can i access javascript functions from ajax loaded content on the same page?

Tags: javascript, ajax

1) on main page i have javascript function

function editSuccess(data) {
    alert("editSuccess called");
    }

2) From main page I load some content into div using ajax
then i need call javascript function from loaded content
but it's don't see editSuccess function

Comment: I had the same problem so what I did was put that function into a .js file and made reference to that .js file in my main script and also in my ajax script. Should do the trick.

Comment: What URL is the loaded content coming from? You may be running into problems with the same origin policy: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work as long as `editSuccess` is available in the global scope. Remember that JavaScript has function scope, so if you define `editSuccess` inside a function, it will only be available within that function. Consider this example:

```
// javascript
window.onload = function() {
    function editSuccess() {
        alert("Hello");
    }
};

// html
<div onclick='editSuccess()'>..</div>

// or
<script>editSuccess()</script>
```

will not work since `editSuccess` does not exist in the global scope.

Comment: Thank you for fast and helpful answer 
my function has been located under $(document).ready(function() {
and after moving it at the global scope.
all became working